# Change size of blank line in HTML

Tags: html

I'd like to insert a blank line in my HTML code but I'd like to change the size of this blank line to see if it fits with the rest of the page.

Does someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nicest way would be to put a bottom margin on the element you want some spacing after. The other solutions posted are not semantic and your markup will end up to be a giant mess of spacer elements without content.

**CSS** is the right way for presentation.

For example if you have two paragraphs, and want some spacing after the first one:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Blabla</p>
<p>Blabla 2</p>
```

This is just an illustration, your best bet would be using `id` / `class` and a separate stylesheet.

The only other semantic solution I can think of is a [`<HR>` element](http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html), but it is a quite problematic one if you want to style it cross-browser (see details on the link).

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like:

```
<p style="height: 200px"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp) css property?

Like this:
    `<span style="line-height: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>`

Answer (score 2):

You could insert a div and change the height with css?

```
<div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
.spacer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

But a better solution would be to put a bottom margin on the element preceding the space you want.

```
  <div class="some_content">
    The stuff before the space
  </div>

  <!-- space here -->
```

CSS

```
  .some_content {
    margin-bottom: 100px
  }
```

Would give you a 100px space below the content.